# parse_str randomly adding semicolons to keys

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, query-string

I am passing a query string as part of my query string to a PHP script.

Kinda like this:

```
$.post('/url', {
    id: postID
    filters: $('#form').serialize()
});
```

Then in my PHP, I use `parse_str` to read `filters`:

```
<?php
$postID = $this->input->post('id');
parse_str($this->input->post('filters'), $filters);
```

The problem is that `parse_str` is adding `;`s randomly to the keys.  I'm getting a result like this:

```
array(4) {
  ["users"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["companies;"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["pref;_123"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["products;"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "1234"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "5678"
  }
}
```

Why is the server adding `;`?  I tried it on another server, and this doesn't happen.  It also doesn't happen when testing via CLI.

**EDIT**: Seems this is not `parse_str`'s fault, but some sort of XSS filter.  `$this->input->post('filters')` (and even `$_POST['filters']`!) contains the `;` characters.  I checked, and jQuery is not adding them.

**EDIT**: I managed to "fix" this by doing:

```
$filters = array_combine(array_map(function($x){
    return str_replace(';', '', $x);
}, array_keys($filters)), array_values($filters));
```

Comment: I would first do a var_dump of the $filters to see what is coming in.

Comment: Do you see anything weird in the Ajax request? Or the issue is only with PHP? Can you reproduce the problem using a static string, like `parse_str("users=&companies=...")`?

Comment: Hmm: `$this->input->post('filters')` seems to contain the `;` characters it.  Seems it's not `parse_str`'s fault.

Comment: What version of CodeIgniter you running? See [this thread](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/84137/)

Comment: @JordanArseno: CodeIgniter 2.  Thing is `$_POST['filters']` also adds the `;`.

Comment: Interesting. You say jQuery is not adding them - is this from a `console.log()` or from inspecting HTTP headers? Have you checked both?

Comment: @JordanArseno: Both.  Chrome's dev tools show that the string is being POSTed as I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is caused by the config variable `global_xss_filtering` in Codeigniter. Set it to false to disable this behaviour.

See also:
[xss_clean adds semicolon to anything with an &](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/84137/)
[CodeIgniter adding semicolons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707913/codeigniter-adding-semicolons)

Comment: Even `$_POST['filters']` contains the `;` characters!

Comment: Doesn't seem like that can be set at runtime.  `$this->config->set_item('global_xss_filtering', FALSE);` didn't help.

Answer (score 2):

I would first do a var_dump of the $filters to see what is coming in.

[parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) will parse the string you send it like so:

```
$string = "user=&companies=StackOverflow";
parse_str($string, $filters);
echo $filters['user']; // empty string
echo $filters['companies']; // StackOverflow
```

My best guess is that what is being sent from [iQuery's serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) (inclusive of the data) is not properly serialized/escaped probably so parse_str can easily split the string with the & as the separator for key/value of each parameter.

Reading the manuals you are definitely doing things correctly there but there might be something lurking in your data that throws the parse_str off. I would also look for illegal characters in the sting posted by jQuery.

Comment: `parse_str` works fine with a manually entered string.  Hmm.... seems `$_POST['filters']` contains the `;` characters.  I checked and jQuery is not adding them.