# Why $_POST can't retieve <img style="">

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I was creating in my textarea like this:

```
<img style="padding-right:5px; width:200px; height:200px;" src="assets/images/logo.jpg">
```

And then I post it to PHP using ajax. And the in the PHP response like this:

```
<img right;width:200px;height:200px;" src="assets/images/logo.jpg">
```

*`style="padding-"` is missing.*

My Question is: why PHP can't retrieve `style=padding-` with `$_POST`? Anybody can resolve this? Thanks.. Sorry My English is Bad

Comment: How are you posting it? show your ajax code.

Comment: php doesn't support to post the styles, it only supports the input fields values

Comment: Can you show how you are making the AJAX call?  Are you doing anything to the value before POSTing it?

Comment: @KrishR: I think he's trying to post the *literal* HTML string.

Comment: i look at firebugs, the post tab is correct (include <style="padding-"), but in response tab is not correct (<style="padding-" is missing).

Comment: OP could do a work-around and place that information in a variable to be transmitted as text with the post. @jhonderiva are you trying to do an upload?

Comment: @jhonderiva: What does your PHP code look like?  What do you see (in the response tab) if you do `var_dump($_POST);`?

Comment: Run your form through an html validator. you've probably got bad code somewhere before your textarea.

Comment: @JayBlanchard : i wan't to save the <img style="padding- ..."> to database, not upload.. i was try with single quote, but not success.. style="padding-" is missing. how to it to transmitted as text? in my ajax code, dataType: "html"

Comment: @jhonderiva: That `dataType` is what jQuery is expecting as the *response*.  Can you post your `$.ajax` code and your PHP file?

Comment: Make sure in doing this that you are not opening your site up to code injection attacks, my guess is that you currently have a significant vulnerability here.

Comment: @RocketHazmat : is not my expecting, the response still missing style="padding-"

Comment: my ajax code : $.ajax({
            url:host+"posting/moduleControl/posting/save/"+param,
            data:{'ID':post_id,'JUDUL':judulPostingan,"POSTING":isi_postingan,'IDX_POSTING_CATEGORY_ID':kategori,'ALLOW_COMMENTS':is_komen},
            dataType:'html',
            type:'post',
            success:function(resp){
                
            }
    })

Comment: my php: $post = array();
                foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
                    $post[$key] = $this->input->post($key);
                } print_r($post);

Comment: Update your question to contain the code, posting as a comment makes it lose formatting

Comment: the response in php is [POSTING] => <p>Testing BOSSSS<img  left; width: 357.835px; height: 314px;" src="assets/images/logo.jpg"><br></p>

Comment: the post is : POSTING <p>Testing BOSSSS<img style="float: left; width: 357.835px; height: 314px;" src="assets/images/logo.jpg"><br></p>

Comment: `$this->input->post($key);`.  That's CodeIgniter!  My guess is that what you are seeing is because of its XSS filter (`$config['global_xss_filtering']` is probably set to `true`).  Try `$this->input->post($key, FALSE);`

Comment: Still Same... <style="float: is missing...

Comment: There's some filtering going on.  Not sure if it's CodeIgniter or PHP itself, but something is filtering the input.

Comment: OK @RocketHazmat you're great man.. yeah.. XSS filter still on in my config.php .. thanks guy...

Comment: @jhonderiva: You're welcome! :-D  I remember having a similar issue some time ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12305802/parse-str-randomly-adding-semicolons-to-keys

Comment: @RocketHazmat : please put your comment in Answer palce ... Thanks brother...

Answer (score 0):

Total guess but it your quotes. If you are posting using double quotes `"`, and the script contains double qoutes `"` it could be interrupting the end of line correctly.

Try changing to single quotes `'` and see if that helps.

```
<img style='padding-right:5px; width:200px; height:200px;' src='assets/images/logo.jpg'>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is CodeIgniter's `global_xss_filtering`.  It is filtering the `$_POST` variable before you read it in.

Try to change `$config['global_xss_filtering']` to `false` in your `config.php` file.